# Idiomatic scala way to implement this simple split-like function

Tags: scala, haskell

I'd like to implement a function that has the following characteristics:

- take an `array` (`Array[A]`) and a number of `pieces` to return (`Int`) as parameters
- returns the `array` array split in `pieces` pieces.
- all pieces should be of equal length if possible, else the first ones should be one element longer to the last ones (if the length of `array` isn't a multiple of `pieces`)

in Haskell I would have coded something along those lines:

```
split :: [a] -> Int -> [[a]]
split list pieces = go list (length list `div` pieces)
 where
  go xs n | l > n && m == 0 = take n xs : go (drop n xs) n
          | l > n           = take (n + 1) xs : go (drop (n + 1) xs) n
          | otherwise       = [xs]
   where
    l = length xs
    m = l `mod` n
```

Though in Scala I encounter many difficulties to code this (basic) function. For the recursion first, `Array` doesn't seem that adapted. Then, the `if` structure that'd allow me to implement the kind of guards I'm using in haskell aren't allowed in place of an expression, which seems weird to me. Another problem I have is that I wouldn't know how to make my scala code polymorphic (as my Haskell code is). Last but not least, I don't get how I'd go about making not only the `a` equivalent polymorphic, but also the `Array` instance, because there are many basic collections in Scala.

I'd be fine with <strike>either a complete explained solution or</strike> simple hints to answer my misunderstandings.

Comment: Actually it's not. `.grouped(pieces)` will return as many pieces as needed that are `pieces` long. I want this function to return `pieces` pieces.

Comment: It's closer than you might think. If there's a `transpose`-alike, then you can transpose the result of `.grouped(pieces)`... though that would not preserve the order of the elements, if that's important.

Comment: Is it a progfun course of rewriting haskell programs to scala?

Comment: progfun? What's that? :p I'm just trying to get to know Scala for univ before the big projects :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The translation is pretty straight forward. Instead of calling `take` and `drop` separately, I use `splitAt` which is potentially more efficient. Of course, you could make this tail-recursive. And I would also argue that "idiomatic" Scala might be using `IndexedSeq.newBuilder` inside the method, which is probably again more efficient, but I guess that's not what you are looking for.

Note that Scala's arrays are mutable, so you'd want `Vector` or the more general `IndexedSeq` instead.

```
import collection.immutable.{IndexedSeq => ISeq}

def split[A](seq: ISeq[A], pieces: Int): ISeq[ISeq[A]] = {
  val n = seq.size / pieces
  def loop(xs: ISeq[A]): ISeq[ISeq[A]] = {   
    val l = xs.size
    if(l > n) {
      val m = l % n
      val (begin, end) = xs.splitAt(if(m == 0) n else n + 1)
      begin +: loop(end)
    } else ISeq(xs)
  }
  loop(seq)
}

split(1 to 20, 3) // correct
```

Comment: I just had finished a working version in an ugly imperative style. Thanks for the example I was looking for :)